# How to read through a text file in row and column wise manner

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file with data in 3 columns, such as

```
1 1 -1
1 -1 -1
-1 1 1
1 1 1
-1 1 1
```

Now, I want to check if the row contains at least one "1", if so print "1" in the output file corresponding to the row. If none of the columns in the row contain "1", then print "-1" in the output file corresponding to the row.

I do not know how to process the text file using row*column wise manner. Can u help me process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program iterates over the rows of the input file, emitting either "1" or "-1" for each row.

`for row in input_file` loops over all of the rows, assigning each of them to the variable `row` in turn.

`row.split()` creates an array of strings, where each string represents one column in that row.

`if '1' in row.split()` is true at least one of the items returned by `row.split()` is exactly `'1'`.

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
  for row in input_file:
    if '1' in row.split():
      print 1
    else:
      print -1
```